# vmc tunnel not working on api.cloudfoundry.com with Ruby 2.0

Tags: cloud-foundry, tunnel, vmc

I am trying to tunnel the `mysql` service on `api.cloudfoundry.com` but facing the error below.

I have installed `Ruby 2.0`

installed gem versions :
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
addressable (2.3.3, 2.2.8),async_sinatra (0.5.0),bigdecimal (1.2.0),caldecott (0.0.5),caldecott-client (0.0.2),cf-uaa-lib (1.3.10),cfoundry (0.5.3.rc5),clouseau (0.0.2),
em-http-request (0.3.0),em-websocket (0.3.8),escape_utils (0.3.2),eventmachine (1.0.3 ruby x86-mingw32),interact (0.5.2),io-console (0.4.2),json (1.7.7, 1.6.8),json_pure (1.7.7),
manifests-vmc-plugin (0.6.3.rc2),mime-types (1.21),minitest (4.3.2),mothership (0.5.1),
multi_json (1.7.0),multipart-post (1.2.0),psych (2.0.0),rack (1.5.2),rack-protection (1.5.0),rake (0.9.6),rdoc (4.0.0),rest-client (1.6.7),rubygems-update (2.0.3),
rubyzip (0.9.9),sinatra (1.4.1),test-unit (2.0.0.0),tilt (1.3.6),tunnel-vmc-plugin (0.2.2),
uuidtools (2.1.3),vmc (0.5.1.rc4)
```

`C:\Users\user>vmc` tunnel
`DL` is deprecated, please use `Fiddle`

1: mongo-hello

2: mysql-hello

3: rabbit-hello

Which service instance?> 2

1: none

2: mysql

3: mysqldump

Which client would you like to start?> 2

```
Opening tunnel on port 10000... FAILED
CFoundry::BadResponse: 400: <h2>Client sent a bad request.</h2>
```

For more information, see `~/.vmc/crash`

crash contents:

```
Time of crash:
  2013-03-20 17:30:10 +0530

CFoundry::BadResponse: 400: <h2>Client sent a bad request.</h2>

<<<
REQUEST: GET http://api.cloudfoundry.com/apps/caldecott
REQUEST_HEADERS:
  Accept : application/json
  Authorization : bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjEzNjQwOTc3OTksInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFtdWxsYXdvcmtAZ21haWwuY29tIiwic2NvcGUiOlsiY2xvdWRfY29udHJvbGxlci5yZWFkIiwib3BlbmlkIiwicGFzc3dvcmQud3JpdGUiXSwiZW1haWwiOiJhbXVsbGF3b3JrQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImF1ZCI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJjbG91ZF9jb250cm9sbGVyIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiXSwianRpIjoiOGEzYmNhYzEtOTdjMC00OGY2LWE1YjAtNmZhNjFkNTM1YzRiIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6Ijc1NGE0YmE0LTQxNDMtNDA1NC05OWE3LWRkOGJlYTA1NzMyOSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InZtYyJ9.bgY7BUi7DpjKL4gy5YkbTJDYuYXHhHPzKPZApabeA_dpRLfcr1yhprlx2Yx1Shavdso-R9jYg3jiy9MuTUhZ6hvIVVoKcaFxcw43owb2ztXxb_VM6N2wmyXnLX5dmSXNIv7xa5hgbeuwE32rSR66sLNGEgHu-sreaKQIN9V6GbOe-Bj4WN-uux0O8AGmol5sp1QhD4Nf2nAmsiPHR63OhS6-SDBYgizcmpfWgwGeOMvcTumbYJ6PpvRNPa20pQomjDOqSY2Jn_tQM7RfZCklpyZKvdt2RIQK5fWAekMLWlnG3aJYHE90UHnxg0UclhwzgrgI0HiDWkQ_42dqOX446g
  Content-Length : 297
  Content-Type : application/json
REQUEST_BODY: {"name":"caldecott","instances":1,"staging":{"model":"sinatra","stack":"ruby19","command":"bundle exec ruby server.rb -p $VCAP_APP_PORT"},"resources":{"memory":64},"env":["CALDECOTT_AUTH=9d498baf-9102-4c80-851d-f400530a261f"],"uris":["caldecott-b58c1.cloudfoundry.com"],"services":["mysql-hello"]}
RESPONSE: [400]
RESPONSE_HEADERS:
  content-type : text/html
RESPONSE_BODY:
<h2>Client sent a bad request.</h2>
>>>

cfoundry-0.5.3.rc5/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:167:in `handle_error_response'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc5/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:137:in `handle_response'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc5/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:87:in `request'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc5/lib/cfoundry/baseclient.rb:72:in `post'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc5/lib/cfoundry/v1/model_magic.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in define_client_methods'
cfoundry-0.5.3.rc5/lib/cfoundry/v1/model.rb:83:in `create!'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/tunnel.rb:145:in `push_helper'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/tunnel.rb:88:in `create_helper'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/tunnel.rb:28:in `open!'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:41:in `block in tunnel'
interact-0.5.2/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.2/lib/tunnel-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:40:in `tunnel'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/base.rb:66:in `run'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:72:in `block in invoke'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:86:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:86:in `invoke'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/base.rb:55:in `execute'
vmc-0.5.1.rc4/lib/vmc/cli.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
vmc-0.5.1.rc4/lib/vmc/cli.rb:161:in `save_token_if_it_changes'
vmc-0.5.1.rc4/lib/vmc/cli.rb:149:in `block in execute'
vmc-0.5.1.rc4/lib/vmc/cli.rb:100:in `wrap_errors'
vmc-0.5.1.rc4/lib/vmc/cli.rb:145:in `execute'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership.rb:45:in `start'
vmc-0.5.1.rc4/bin/vmc:11:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Ruby200/bin/vmc:23:in `load'
D:/Ruby200/bin/vmc:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the caldecott application and then trying the tunnel again;

```
$ vmc delete caldecott
$ vmc tunnel
```